# C++ Equivalent of %ld in Java for String.format()

Tags: java, string.format

For instance, `%11.2lf` in C++ becomes `%11.2f` in Java.
How about for long format?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

As you may have worked out, it's not necessary to specify the `l` flag. According to [the docs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax), a decimal integer is specified by `d` just like in C++.  So the answer is just `%d`.

Comment: %d wouldn't suffice if the value you are trying to print is long. In that case, you have to parse it.

Comment: @Milli: While I'm not sure about the 1st sentence (don't think signedness is a consideration), I just confirmed experimentally that %d will correctly format longs!

Comment: You are RIGHT! My bad.. I had also String in the same statement with long.. The error was caused by the %d %d while it should have been %d %s. Thank you Andrzej!

Comment: @CarlSmotricz is correct, signedness has nothing to do with it. I cleaned up the question to remove that.

Comment: String.format() will throw java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException at runtime if you use the 'l' flag with the 'd' flag (e.g. %ld) (demonstrated on Java 7).

Answer (score 54):

Use `%d` for decimals (long, int).  It works OK.  E.g.:

```
System.err.println(String.format("%d", 193874120937489387L));
```

...will print just fine.  Read up on [`java.util.Formatter`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) for more details.  `%d` will take a `long`, no problem.

Comment: WORKS PERFECT!!